# Google Play Billing V6 Purchase Flow does not open

Tags: java, android, billing

Today I ran into a strange problem. Yesterday I have implemented the BIlling V6 Subscription into my App, and everything worked fine. Today, when I created a new version of my App, I had to recognize, that the PurchaseFlow Window simply does not open.

```
 public void PurchaseFlow(){
        // An activity reference from which the billing flow will be launched.

    BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Log.e("RemoveAds", "setupfinished");
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
                        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                .setProductList(
                                        ImmutableList.of(
                                                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                        .setProductId("cheatr.primem")
                                                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                                        .build()))
                                .build();
                billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                        queryProductDetailsParams,
                        new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                            public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                                 List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "onProductDetailsResponse callback triggered");
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "ProductDetailsList size: " + productDetailsList.size());
                                String productListString = productDetailsList.toString();
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "Product Details List PFLOW: " + productListString);
                                ProductDetails details = productDetailsList.get(0);
                                SubscriptionPrice = details.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(1).getFormattedPrice();
                                selofferToken = details.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken();
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "Subprice: "
                                        + SubscriptionPrice);
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "SelofferToken: "
                                        + selofferToken);
                                finalizedproddetails = details;
                                Log.e("RemoveAds", "FinalizedDetails: "
                                        + finalizedproddetails);

                                if(billingClient != null) {
                                    ImmutableList productDetailsParamsList =
                                            ImmutableList.of(
                                                    BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                                            // retrieve a value for "productDetails" by calling queryProductDetailsAsync()
                                                            .setProductDetails(finalizedproddetails)
                                                            // to get an offer token, call ProductDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                                                            // for a list of offers that are available to the user
                                                            .setOfferToken(selofferToken)
                                                            .build()
                                            );

                                    BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                                            .build();

                                    billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this, billingFlowParams);
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "Billingresponse: "
                                            + billingResult);
                                }
                                else{
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "Client not Ready !!!");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });
```

// Launch the billing flow
}`

Moreover, the SubscriptionPrice of my Product is just null and does not show in my Log either, even though the SubscriptionDetailslIst is not empty and appears normal. All has worked yesterday and it still works in Debug Mode, but when I create an Internal Test, it stops working. Has anybody ever had a problem like that? I just don't understand why it works in Debug and in Release not.
Thank you in advance!

```
` public void initSubscription(){
        Log.e("RemoveAds", "initsubscription");
        BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                Log.e("RemoveAds", "setupfinished");
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
                            QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setProductList(
                                            ImmutableList.of(
                                                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                            .setProductId("cheatr.primem")
                                                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                                            .build()))
                                    .build();
                    getPurchasedHistory();
                    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                            queryProductDetailsParams,
                            new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                                public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                                     List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "onProductDetailsResponse callback triggered");

                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "ProductDetailsList size: " + productDetailsList.size());
                                    String productListString = productDetailsList.toString();
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "Product Details List of INIT: " + productListString);
                                    ProductDetails details = productDetailsList.get(0);
                                    SubscriptionPrice = details.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(1).getFormattedPrice();
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "SubPRICE INIT:" + SubscriptionPrice);

                                    selofferToken = details.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken();
                                    Log.e("RemoveAds", "Subprice: "
                                               + SubscriptionPrice);
                                    finalizedproddetails = details;
                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        });
    }`
```